# Require.js Loads Dependency from Wrong Path

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

With the following Require.js config, loading `moduledep` from within `module` is fetching the dependency from the root (`/moduledep.js`) of the app rather than the mapped path (`/assets/path/module/moduledep.js`).

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    "module": "assets/path/module"
  },

  map: {
    "module": {
      "moduledep": "assets/path/module/moduledep"
    }
  }
});
```

Is there any reason that require would be ignoring the mapped path?

Comment: Are you actually using the name "module" or is that for demo purposes? If so, it might be a conflict with the built-in "module" prop.

Comment: I used `module` and `moduledep` as placeholders for the actual assets. Sorry that wasn't clear.

Comment: just making sure... you never know

Comment: are all of your other modules being found? is your baseUrl set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that functionality has its limitations.

From the docs:

> This feature only works well for scripts that are real AMD modules
>   that call define() and register as anonymous modules. Also, **only use
>   absolute module IDs** for map config. Relative IDs (like
>   '../some/thing') do not work.

Comment: This turned out to be an issue with defining dependencies in the module using `require` rather than `define`. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!